# Which image within the visual assets list, corresponds to Cortana

Tags: win-universal-app, cortana

I am currently creating an UWA that interacts with Cortana, but the image displayed at the top of the canvas, remains the default one.

I have tried to declare various images within the visual assets list in , but none of them had a positive impact.

Who knows which one to change? I have read the documentation in MSDN, and they just mentions that cortana displays the app logo but again, I don't know which one is it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Btw, it looks like a sample from your package manifest got cut off in here, you probably need to use a code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your package manifest, you have a line like this (This is taken from a the default UAP app template)

```
<uap:VisualElements
    DisplayName="App10"
    Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
    Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
    Description="App10"
    BackgroundColor="transparent">
```

The element that shows up for me in Cortana's UI when I use a Cortana voice command is the Assets\Square44x44Logo.png one. Is that the one you're trying to change? Keep in mind you can use automatic scaling for different DPIs (it'll look up a file like Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png and other variations depending on the DPI of the screen) so it might be preferring that over the file you've modified, perhaps?

Btw,

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly. What I did was to reference an image for this category (Square44x44 Logo) but because you have the choice with multiple sizes (176px, 88px, 44px, etc..) I decided to upload an image for the biggest size. I have created a new one with size 44x44px and it's ok.

Comment: Ah, yes. it will probably be particular about the resolution of the image you load. Giving it 88px when it's expecting 44px won't work. If you want to provide higher-dpi versions, use the scaling mechanism [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh965372.aspx) and it'll get applied when the system can use it.